# var vs this in Javascript object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm developing a web framework for node.js. here is the code;

```
function Router(request, response) {
        this.routes = {};

        var parse = require('url').parse;

        var path = parse(request.url).pathname,
            reqRoutes = this.routes[request.method],
            reqRoutesLen = reqRoutes.length;

        ..... // more code

};
```

Should I change all the var to this, like so:

```
function Router(request, response) {
        this.routes = {};

        this.parse = require('url').parse;

        this.path = this.parse(request.url).pathname;
        this.reqRoutes = this.routes[request.method];
        this.reqRoutesLen = this.reqRoutes.length;

        ..... // more code

};
```

Any comments?

Comment: This is a pretty fundamental difference. Are you sure you know what `this` is and what local variables are?

Comment: I have C++ background, Javascript feel strange to me.

Comment: In that case, are you developing a web framework just for fun or learning?  Frameworks like express might be a better choice for your production code while you are learning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572)

Answer (score 13):

Add properties to `this` when you want the properties to persist with the life of the object in question. Use `var` for local variables.

*edit* — as Bergi notes in a comment, variables declared with `var` don't *necessarily* vanish upon return from a function invocation. They are, and remain, directly accessible only to code in the scope in which they were declared, and in lexically nested scopes.

Comment: Notice that local variables can persist with the life of the object as well if referenced from a closure.

Answer (score 1):

It on depends what you want to do.

If you declare the variables with `var`, then they are local to the function and cannot be accessed outside.

If you assign the variables to `this`, then they will be set as properties of the context object the function is called on.

So if e.g. if you write:

```
var obj = new Router();
```

then `obj` will have all the variables as properties and you can changed them. If you call

```
somobject.Router()
```

then all the variables will be set as properties of `someobject`.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of properties hung from `this` sort of like instance variables in other languages (sort of).

It looks like you're creating a constructor function and will likely add some prototype methods.  If that's the case, and you need access to `routes`, you've got it, but not `path`.

```
Router.prototype = {
  doSomething: function(){
    this.routes; // available
    path; // not available
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `var` in the constructor is usually used for private variable while using `this.` is used for public variable.

Example with `this.` :

```
function Router() {
    this.foo = "bar";

    this.foobar = function () {
         return this.foo;
    }
}

var r = new Router();
r.foo // Accessible
```

Example with `var` :

```
function Router() {
    var _foo = "bar";

    this.foobar = function () {
         return _foo;
    }
}

var r = new Router();
r._foo // Not accessible
```