# Are these two code fragments the same (using var vs. using this)

Tags: javascript

I saw some code that looks like this:

```
function foo(bar) {
   this.bar = bar;
};
```

can you rewrite it like this:

```
function foo(bar) {
   var bar = bar;
};
```

because then you don't need to keep writing `this` which is nicer.  Do these two bits of code do the same thing?

Many thanks.

Comment: no, they don't :) they do completely different things

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418669/javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object)

Comment: I think a little wider context would be relevant - these might be used to form a closure, or expose object properties on a function

Comment: One is a local variable, the other a property of an object.

Comment: What is your goal?  Are you sticking with one parameter or are you going to have multiple parameters associated to your function call?

Comment: See other possible duplicate [var vs this. in Javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4946625/1048572)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Using `this`

This creates a property of *a object*. It is public, with read-write access. Depending on how the function was invoked (with `new`?), `this` will point to a different object.  [More on the subject here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

```
function foo(bar) {
   this.bar = bar;
};

foo(10);
console.log(bar); // bar or this.bar .. prints 10

var tmp = new foo(20); 
console.log(tmp.bar); // prints 20
console.log(bar);     // still prints 10
```

### Using `var`

This creates a local variable (note: the variable is already in scope via the function argument). This is local, accesible only from the scope of the `foo` function.

```
function foo(bar) {
   var bar = bar;
}
```

### When use which?

Unless you write oo js, you'd probably want to stick with the second option, or even better - skip the redefinition of `bar` whatsoever. You gain all the usual benefits of encapsulation.

```
function foo(bar) {
   // just use argument bar 
}
```

Comment: and it is also worth mentioning, that it is *cruicial* **how** the function `foo` gets invoked, since it decides the value of `this` and where the data is written.

Answer (score 4):

They are not the same. In the first example you are creating a new property called `bar` on the `foo` object, meaning you could do this to access the assigned value from outside the function (used as an object constructor):

```
function foo(bar) {
   this.bar = bar;
};
var f = new foo(1);
console.log(f.bar);    // => 1
```

In the second example you're creating a variable called `bar` which is not accessible outside of the function.

Comment: Doesn't it need to be `new foo(1)` ?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is if you have otehr function in your function scope like this :

```
function foo(bar) {
   var foo = bar;
    alert(bar); //works

    $.ajax({
      [....],
      success : function(response) {
           alert(bar);//not works
           alert(foo);//works
      }
      });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo(bar) {
    this.bar = bar; 
    // this == window -if foo()
    // this == a -if a = new foo();
};
```

---

```
foo('asd'); // assigns 'asd' to global variable window.bar
console.log(bar); //logs 'asd' (window.bar)
```

---

```
var a = new foo('asd');
console.log(a.bar); // logs 'asd'
console.log(bar); // logs undefined
```

---

```
function foo(bar) {
    var bar2 = bar; //bar2 acts only in scope of this function
};
```